# DevicePolicyManger().getCurrentFailedPasswordAttempts crashes app

Tags: android, device-admin, android-5.0-lollipop

Seems like some of the DeviceAdmin functionality has been broken in Lollipop, at least on my Nexus 5.

This works perfectly on KitKat, JellyBean and Ice Cream Sandwich

```
@Override
public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) {

    DevicePolicyManager policyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    if(policyManager != null){
        int attempts = policyManager.getCurrentFailedPasswordAttempts();
        Log.v("TAG", "Attempts = " + attempts);
    }
}
```

But on my Nexus 5 with Android 5.0 Lollipop it produces the following error:

```
11-24 16:11:50.117  27053-27053/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 27053
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.myapp.receivers.AdminReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.content.pm.UserInfo.id' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2586)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.content.pm.UserInfo.id' on a null object reference
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
            at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.getCurrentFailedPasswordAttempts(IDevicePolicyManager.java:2476)
            at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.getCurrentFailedPasswordAttempts(DevicePolicyManager.java:1261)
            at com.example.myapp.receivers.AdminReceiver.onPasswordFailed(AdminReceiver.java:48)
            at android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver.onReceive(DeviceAdminReceiver.java:417)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2579)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

[It's been reported as an issue in the L-preview as well.](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1082&q=type%3Ddefect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&start=100)

**My question, what is causing this?**

Comment: FYI: my app has the same problem so you are not alone. I "solved" it with a simple try catch block - at least the app will not crash anymore.

Comment: Thanks @TheisBorg - For now, I'll just be keeping a static reference to unlock attempts, until a hero comes and saves the day..

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error then I realised that it may not work for the version 5.0 and above versions.So what I did is I am checking number of wrong attempts programmatically.Like If the someone wants to unlock pattern or pin if he enters wrong then receiver will catch and calls the passwordFailed() method.So I created on SharedPreference object and I am storing the number of passwordFailed() method is called. Based on that I am getting number of wrong patterns.I think this is correct way or not I don't know.